# Combining 2xMSI and 1xEXE into a single installer

Tags: windows, windows-installer, exe

I have 3 files -

1. Alky for Applications.msi ( which make Vista Apps work on XP)
2. Windows Vista sidebar.exe ( Which make that VIsta sidebar work on XP)
3. Gadget Extractor.msi (A part of number 2)

Now, the problem is that all the 3 applications are installers and I want to merge them to 1 installer. So please tell me what should I do and I also want to remove some content (normal files) from 2.

Note: I do **NOT** want to bind the files, so that 3 installers start at the same time. I want to make them into one

The Person who is able to help me gets a VPS with cPanel with RL/TF allowed  :D

Comment: You could consider changing the title of your question, so as to be a little more informative...

Comment: The new title isn't exactly accurate because the second file is not an MSI file.

Comment: @musicfreak I just edited it to be more accurate.

Comment: @marcog: Thanks! I would have, but I didn't know how to better word it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a wrapper application. It would contain all three installations. When user runs it, it would extract each installer to a temporary directory and run them separately one after another. When everything is done, you would be able to remove files installed by 2nd app.

Comment: @Netguy, I'd do it this way:
1. Put up all three parts into an exe resources.
2. When users starts your setup application:
2.1. It extracts the first part (Applications.msi) from its resources into a temporary directory.
2.2. It starts with `msiexec.exe /i Applications.msi`, you surely want to add `/passive` and `/norestart` flags to msiexec command line.
2.3. Waits for the process to exit, checks its exit code. If it's zero, then proceeds to the next step; otherwise, installation failed and it exits.
2.4. Delete the temporary file extracted at step 2.1.
2.5. Similarly run setup of parts 2&3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom action, if I remember correct the example of custom action which starts applications during installation was in MSI SDK in early ages. Also you can check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/Installation.aspx) article on CodeProject.

Comment: Well, I didnt understand what you ment , beacuse I am a n00b at software development , If possible please let me know your Email. I would like to know how to merge it or please if possible , you merge it for me.

Comment: Any one Else knows how to do ?